# uuid out of SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier ios not unique

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

The `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` is changed with any reinstall on ios.

Is there a way to track the real device id? in a way that is also allowed by apple?

Out of 4.3 changelogs:

> "iOS: Added support for vendor/advertisement id (iOS6). Changed SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier logic: on ios7 it will use ad id (if tracking is enabled) and fallback to vendor id otherwise. On pre-ios7 the behavior stays the same (hash of MAC address)."